# SQL Database Lost

Tags: mysql

I lost my database and when they restored the files, I had two files in a database directory that I assume are the data for my database.  How do I recover my database using these two files.  wp_options.MYI and wp_options.MYD

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore the database by simply copying those files into the DB folder. (e.g., /var/lib/mysql/dbname). Typically there is a FRM file included as well.

Comment: There is no FRM file. only the MYI and MYD files

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog post to repair corrupt sql database and do it yourself.
http://exchangeserverstips.wordpress.com/2013/12/31/steps-to-repair-sql-server-mdf-file-when-dbcc-checkdb-fails/

Comment: Hi jakson, welcome to WPSE. Even if the link you posted can solve the issue, a link-only answer is not the proper way, because the page can be moved, deleted, and so on. Next time try to add explaination on what is said in the page you link.